# 2 plugins not working simultaneously in pom

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl, pom.xml

I have added 2 plugins under build tag, functionality of both the plugin's is to generate some classes under target folder. Whenever I am trying to `clean install` maven application, by default target gets clean each time and then installs a fresh content into target folder which is the ideal way.

But in the following code Java classes are generated only when, if there is only single plugin. I have to manually comment any one of the plugin and then I need to install maven goal and then Java classes get generated for a single plugin, same thing I need to repeat for second plugin.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/somefolder</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>somefolder</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>myfirstwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>/WEB-INF/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <target>2.2</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsimport</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>mysecondwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>/WEB-INF/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <target>2.2</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My question is, how can I generate Java classes simultaneously without commenting any one of the plugin under target folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying the same plugin twice, that's not going to work. You need to merge the two like this (move `<configuration>` inside `<execution>`):

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
             <id>somefolder</id>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
               <wsdlFiles>
                  <wsdlFile>myfirstwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>/WEB-INF/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <target>2.2</target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>wsimport</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                  <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>mysecondwsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                  </wsdlFiles>
                  <wsdlLocation>/WEB-INF/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
                  <extension>true</extension>
                  <target>2.2</target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert & Gerold.. this is very helpful.